# Sum List<T> Properties of each item in List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, lambda

Please refer to ff. codes:

**MainObj:**

```
public class MainObj {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public List<SubObj> Subojects { get; set; }
}
```

**SubObj:**

```
public class SubObj {
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

**QUESTION:** I have a `List<MainObj>`. Each item has equal number of `SubObj`. How do I sum the values of each `SubObj` from `MainObj A` which corresponds to the same index as the `SubObj` in the other `MainObj` in the list.

To illustrate further:

**Results:**

```
{
    Name: "something....",
    Value: SUM(MainObj_A.SubObj[0], MainObj_B.SubObj[0] .... MainObj_n.SubObj[0]
},
{
    Name: "don't really care...."
    Value: SUM(MainObj_A.SubObj[1], MainObj_B.SubObj[1] .... MainObj_n.SubObj[1]
},
{
    Name: "don't really care...."
    Value: SUM(MainObj_A.SubObj[2], MainObj_B.SubObj[2] .... MainObj_n.SubObj[2]
}
.... so on and so forth
```

I know I can loop thru each item in `MainObj` then perform the sum but I was hoping that there is a simpler way using `Linq`.

Sorry if I can't put the right words for my question. I hope the illustrations helped.

Every help would be much appreciated. **CHEERS!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand the question you look for something like this:

```
var results = list.Select((m, i) => new 
          {
             m.Name, 
             Value = list.Sum(t => t.SubObj[i].Value)
          }).ToList();
```

This creates a list of an anonymous type containing the name of each main object and the sum of all subobject values with the same index as the main object.

---

It's not clear from your question, but if you want to sum *all* subojects (not only as many as there are main objects), you can do it like this:

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, list[0].SubObj.Count)
                        .Select(i => list.Sum(m => m.SubObj[i].Value)).ToList();
```

This gives you a list of the sums (without names, as your examples suggest that you "don't really care" about any names).

Comment: If OP will have a list of 2 mainItems, each with 3 subitems, your code with produce list with 2 items (sum of subitem1 and sum of subitem2), but op want to have a list of 3 items (sum of every subitem).

Comment: @MaksimSimkin the question is not really clear about that, but I added a version to my answer.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin is correct. I will look into your included answer though

Answer (score 2):

For flexibility and slightly boosted performance, I'd prefer a mixed LINQ-sql way as shown in my answer below.

```
var result = from x in list
             where x...
             group x by x.SomeProperty 
             into item
             select new {
             Id = item.Key,
             Name = item.Name,
             Value = item.SubObj.Sum(i => i.Value) 
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would extend solution of Rene, to sum over all subitems:

```
var result = list.First().Subojects.Select((m, i) => new
{
    Name = i.ToString(),
    Value = list.Sum(t => t.Subojects[i].Value)
}).ToList();
```

i have used it with this values:

```
var list = new List<MainObj>
{
    new MainObj { Name = "A", Subojects = new List<SubObj>{new SubObj{ Value = 1}, new SubObj{ Value = 2}, new SubObj{ Value = 3}}},
    new MainObj { Name = "B", Subojects = new List<SubObj>{new SubObj{ Value = 1}, new SubObj{ Value = 2}, new SubObj{ Value = 3}}}
};
```

And result is:

> 0:2 
>   1:4 
>   2:6